# what are the difference between thread.exit and thread.pass in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am learning ruby and its concepts. I am reading an [article](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_threads.html) on "threads in ruby" in which unable to distinguish thread.pass and thread.exit. The article contains definitions of these two methods as: The **Thread.pass** method invokes the thread scheduler to pass execution to another thread. The **Thread.exit** method terminates the currently running thread and schedules another thread to be run.

But I am confused while using these methods. Can u please help me to sort out. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thread.pass gives way to other threads to be executed but eventually, the scheduler will pass execution back to it. Thread.exit terminates the thread (and as a consequence tells the scheduler to pass execution to another thread). I hope this helps. If not, please include the code that provokes the confusion.

```
t1 = Thread.new do
  10.times do |i|
    if i < 5
      puts i
      sleep 0.1
      Thread.pass
    else
      Thread.exit
    end
  end
end

sleep 0.05

t2 = Thread.new do
  10.times do |i|
    puts i
    sleep 0.1
  end
end

t1.join
t2.join
```

this will have the following output:

```
0
0
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: But does it mean that after thread.exit executed, the exited thread will be sleep forever or at what time interval it will be invoked again.

Comment: It will never be invoked again.

Comment: Can u provide me the best stuff for the same? I mean either link or blogs....thanks